# Django Invalid Syntax error def index(request)

Tags: python, django

```
File "/home/david/Django-Development/csruipa/ruth/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ruth import views
File "/home/david/Django-Development/csruipa/ruth/views.py", line 4
    def index(request)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax enter code here
```

this is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from ruth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

and this is the view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request)
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

this is the main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^ruth/', include('ruth.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I'm following django tutorial here 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

my error said it's on line 4 this line `def index(request)`
and on urls.py on line 3 which is this `from ruth import views`
on the main urls.py line 6 was the error which is this `url(r'^ruth/', include('ruth.urls')),` line
I'm new to python, I need some help thanks.

Comment: The syntax error points out that you are missing a `:` on the `def` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code block within every function starts with a colon (:)

```
def index(request): #  you missed the semicolon 
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

Comment: Good God I've checked again the tutorial yes you're right, thank you for pointing that out.